# Can we alter the dbspace of a informix table?

Tags: informix

Suppose I have following schema.

```
create table tb1
(col1 Integer,
 col2 varchar(50)
) in dbspace1 extent size 1000 next 500 lock mode row;
```

and I want to change the dbspace of above table to dbspace2 . After doing my alteration table schema should be look like as follows .

```
create table tb1
(col1 Integer,
 col2 varchar(50)
) in dbspace2 extent size 1000 next 500 lock mode row;
```

Is it possible to do? If it is possible what is the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, the [`ALTER FRAGMENT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0236.htm) statement and the [`INIT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0084.htm#ids_sqs_0084) clause allows you to write:

```
ALTER FRAGMENT ON TABLE tb1 INIT IN dbspace2;
```

The keyword TABLE is required; you could specify an index instead.

I've not actually experimented to prove that it works, but the syntax diagram certainly allows it.

Comment: I tried with that and it seems works. I can see empty chunks are filling on dbspace2.  Can I change the default dbspace of the database to this new dbspace2. Because I'm going to remove dbspace1

Comment: Nope. In Informix you cannot alter the base dbspace of a database. You will have to create a new database on the dbspace of your choice, if you want to change it. If the database was created in `dbspace1`, all the sys catalog tables were also created in that dbspace.

Comment: Is it safe to run above query in online.

Comment: Probably, but I'd make sure I have a backup first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when I add online keyword with above comand it will end up with following error .25834  The specified alter fragment operation cannot be performed online. is that mean I cant do this in online ? if it is not possible why it is available in documentation?

Comment: Yes; the message means that ONLINE cannot be used with that operation.  It's likely because it is changing the dbspace; ONLINE operations tend not to involve cross-dbspace operations.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried with above command for table with 3 million of records. It takes around 6minits to complete. But I need to alter another table which has 300 millions of records. I guess it will takes more than 6 hours. But When considering the application level it not practical to take that much downtime. So I need to optimize above command to run fast. Can we use above command with the help of parallel processes. Is there anyway to mention it in this command.

Comment: Life is about to get interesting.  I suspect that you may need to use something other than the INIT clause to ALTER FRAGMENT.  For example, you may need to add another fragment in the other dbspace and ensure that all new rows are placed in the new fragment.  Then you arrange to (slowly) update the old rows so that they migrate from the old fragment to the new; then you drop the now empty old fragment.  I'd need to do some experimentation, though, to be sure it is doable.